# Using spring.batch.job.names with Spring Boot 3 and Spring Batch 5

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm migrating an application with batches to Spring Boot 3/Spring Batch 5.

At the moment we start the batches via a cron job on the server and pass multiple job names, that should be executed.

We use the Property `spring.batch.job.names` for this.

It seems like this does not work anymore with Spring Boot 3/Batch 5.

- Running a single job with `spring.batch.job.name` (without the 's' at the end) works
- Using `spring.batch.job.names` leads to error 'Job name must be specified in case of multiple jobs'
- Using `spring.batch.job.name` (without the 's' at the end) with multiple Jobs (like jobA,jobB) does not run anything

Any ideas? I could find anything in the migration guide. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/wiki/Spring-Batch-5.0-Migration-Guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't find that in the Spring Batch documentation as that is a Spring Boot feature.

For which there is documentation in the [migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#multiple-batch-jobs).

> **Multiple Batch Jobs**
>
> Running multiple batch jobs is no longer supported. If the auto-configuration detects a single job is, it will be executed on startup. If multiple jobs are found in the context, a job name to execute on startup must be supplied by the user using the `spring.batch.job.name` property.